# The abrupt opening and closing of the period-3 window

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm currently trying to work through the following two exercises from Robert L. Devaney's "A First Course in Chaotic Dynamical Systems" [p. 95].

> In Figure 8.5, note the sudden appearance of the period-3 cycle and its window. Explain why this window opens so suddenly.

${}$

> In Figure 8.5, the period-3 window also closes abruptly. Explain why the orbit of $0$ suddenly occupies a much larger interval as the period-3 window closes.

I don't want to get into copyright issues with "Figure 8.5", so I will instead modify the questions to deal with the logistic map $x \mapsto r x(1-x)$, and [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#/media/File:Logistic_Bifurcation_map_High_Resolution.png) from Wikipedia.

**What I want to know is why does the period-3 window open and close abruptly.**

I'm not even sure that I understand the questions, but regardless, my reasoning is as follows.

- **Opening:** since $3$ is an odd number the period-3 window cannot come up out of a period doubling bifurcation.
- **Closing:** No idea.

I would appreciate if anyone explained the meaning of the questions (i.e. the words "suddenly" and "abruptly"), and also help in giving more convincing arguments than mine.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363571) might be relevant. While it doesn't address the vague notion of "abruptness" directly, I think that can be inferred from the very specific algebraic cause of the bifurcation.